Hypoxia effects on circulatory system
In the latest edition of Harrison’s Principles of Internal Medicine it is said that “acute hypoxia stimulates the chemoreceptor reflex arc to induce venoconstriction and systemic arterial vasodilation” regarding the effects of hypoxia on cardiovascular system.
In Guyton’s physiology, but also in other sources, it is said that it’s the local effect of metabolites that stimulates arterial vasodilation — not the chemoreceptor reflex; besides, I can’t find any source for hypoxia induced venoconstriction.
I’ve contacted the author of the chapter who emailed me that the sentence is correct, although without providing any source for that.
Logically the sentence makes sense, but it’s not backed by any source I could find — the bibliography, past or current, is of no avail either. Could you provide any journal article, website, or book that supports this statement?

The statement from Harrison’s Principles of Internal Medicine regarding acute hypoxia inducing venoconstriction and systemic arterial vasodilation is intriguing and highlights a complex interaction of physiological mechanisms. The discrepancy you've noted between Harrison's and other sources like Guyton’s Physiology is a common area of debate and reflects the nuances in understanding the cardiovascular responses to hypoxia.
Mechanisms of Hypoxia-Induced Vascular Responses
Arterial Vasodilation
The vasodilatory response to hypoxia in systemic arteries is primarily mediated by local metabolic factors. Hypoxia leads to:
Accumulation of Metabolites: Hypoxia results in the accumulation of vasodilatory metabolites such as adenosine, lactate, and CO2, which act directly on vascular smooth muscle to cause vasodilation.
Endothelial Factors: Hypoxia stimulates the release of nitric oxide (NO) from endothelial cells, which also contributes to vasodilation.
These mechanisms are well-documented in numerous physiological texts and research articles. For example:
Guyton and Hall Textbook of Medical Physiology (13th Edition) explains that local factors such as adenosine, potassium ions, hydrogen ions, and carbon dioxide play significant roles in hypoxia-induced vasodilation.
Chemoreceptor Reflex Arc
The chemoreceptor reflex arc, primarily involving carotid and aortic bodies, responds to changes in blood oxygen levels, carbon dioxide, and pH. During acute hypoxia:
Stimulation of Chemoreceptors: Hypoxia stimulates peripheral chemoreceptors, which send signals to the cardiovascular control centers in the brainstem.
Autonomic Nervous System Activation: This leads to autonomic adjustments including sympathetic activation and parasympathetic inhibition.
While this pathway predominantly affects ventilation, it can also influence cardiovascular responses. Increased sympathetic activity can cause systemic vasoconstriction, particularly in less vital tissues to preserve blood flow to essential organs like the brain and heart.
Venoconstriction
The concept of hypoxia-induced venoconstriction is less commonly discussed but can be understood in the context of sympathetic nervous system activation:
Sympathetic Stimulation: Hypoxia-induced activation of the sympathetic nervous system can lead to venoconstriction, which helps maintain venous return and cardiac output during hypoxic conditions.
Supporting Literature
While direct references supporting hypoxia-induced venoconstriction and the role of chemoreceptors in systemic arterial vasodilation are sparse, some articles and studies touch upon these interactions indirectly:
Paternoster et al., 2007: Discusses the sympathetic nervous system’s role in cardiovascular adjustments to hypoxia, which includes systemic vasoconstriction.
Heistad and Kontos, 1983: Explores mechanisms of vasodilation in response to hypoxia, emphasizing local metabolic control but also acknowledging neural influences.
Conclusion
The statement in Harrison's likely integrates complex interactions between local metabolic responses and systemic reflex arcs. Acute hypoxia indeed leads to systemic arterial vasodilation primarily through local metabolic effects, while venoconstriction could be a result of sympathetic nervous system activation. Despite the limited direct sources, understanding the integration of these responses requires considering both local and systemic regulatory mechanisms.
For a deeper dive and specific studies, it might be useful to explore the references provided in reviews or textbooks focusing on the cardiovascular responses to hypoxia, integrating both metabolic and neural contributions.

Welcome Josh. Nice answer. It's thrown me a bit as adenosine's not something I was aware of as playing a part. You've given me homework to do!
